# Margin not displaying after <br /> tag

Tags: html, css, margin, line-breaks

I have the following (excerpted) html:

```
<span id="version">Version 1 <small>Last modified 04/August/2012</small><br>unfinished</span>
```

and the following (excerpted) css:

```
#version {
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: Black;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

#version small {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

Everything displays correctly until after the <br>, where the text isn't adjusted for the margin.  Why isn't it adjusted after the <br>?

Comment: Adding a border may help you understand what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/tvLEu/4/

Answer (score 5):

Because the span is an inline element. Do accomplish what you want, either set the display property on the span to block or inline-block, or change the span to a div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FJqPk/)**

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't notice this behaviour of inline mentioned anywhere.

Comment: There's a good discussion of the differences here http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/